# String trimming in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

I have a API that returns a JSON string. I only want part of the string it returns.

it returns a car style

```
"S 4dr Sedan (1.8L 4cyl 4A)"
"CE 4dr Sedan (1.8L 4cyl 4A)"
"LE 4dr Sedan (1.8L 4cyl 5M)"
"LE 4dr Sedan (1.8L 4cyl 4A)"
```

I want to "string out" everything in the parentheses. I havent really worked with Javascript string editing so I really have no clue on how to do this. Please help.

(any tips are cool too)

ps: Im working with angularJS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out regular expressions, you can select the bits of string you want and drop the rest, i was not sure if you wanted the text in the brackets or you wanted everything but that, my sample uses the stuff before the brackets. you can play around with regex here, i put your sample in there:

https://regex101.com/r/lT8fB3/1

if you want to use what is within the brackets just replace the \1 in the substitution string with \2

In java this could look like this then:

```
String updated = your_json_string.replaceAll("\"\s?(.*)\s\((.*)\)\"", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is remove anything in parentheses from the string, you can use the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method of the string object with a suitable [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var carStyle = "S 4dr Sedan (1.8L 4cyl 4A)";
var s = carStyle.replace( /\(.*\)/ , "");
console.log(s);  // "S 4dr Sedan "
```

The rather cumbersome `/\(.*\)/` is a regular expression that will match parentheses and their contents.

**Note:** As [hexeri-software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988084/hexerei-software) points out in the comments, using `.*` to match what's between the parenthesis [is generally a bad idea](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/06/03/why-using-in-regular-expressions-is-almost-never-what-you-actually-want), so a better regex might be:

```
var s = carStyle.replace( /\([^)]*\)/ , "");
```

Comment: you should always test before using `.*` because it is very greedy - it is correct syntax, but dangerous. i find much safer using the `^` group, so in this case searching until we meet closing brackets ''')'''  - so `/\([^)]*\)/` would be the _safer_ variant

Comment: @hexerei-software good point, added a note with alternate regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression : `/(?=\().*/g`

Example :

```
s = "S 4dr Sedan (1.8L 4cyl 4A)"
x = s.match(/(?=\().*/g)[0]
// will give you an array "(1.8L 4cyl 4A)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression could solve your problem. Here is an example of one that isolates just the text between the two parentheses.
Here is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to learn more about javascript regular expressions:

```js
var first = "S 4dr Sedan (1.8L 4cyl 4A)";


var patt = /\(([^)]*)\)/gi
var res = patt.exec(first);
document.getElementById('first').value = res[1];
```

```html
<label>first
  <input id="first" />
</label>
```